# multithreading in the same class using one for loop and make each each thread display

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to create 3 child threads and 
parent thread must display 1-5 numbers,
child 1 must display 6-10,
child 2 must display 11-15,
child 3 must display 15-20...

and this must be done using one for loop in parent class and one for loop in child class..
Class C is the parent and class D is the child

```
    public class C {

    public static void main(String[] args){
    D d = new D();
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());

    Thread child1= new Thread(d);
    Thread child2= new Thread(d);
    Thread child3= new Thread(d);

    child1.start();
    child2.start();
    child3.start();


    for(int i=1; i<=5;i++){
        System.out.println("From parent thread: " +i);
    }

}

public class D extends Thread{

public void run(){

    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());           


}
```

Comment: Ok, you've described what you want to do.  Now you need to edit your question and add a question.  What specific, programming difficulty are you having?  Include inputs, expected vs actual output, errors, etc.

Comment: I believe its a home task or something.

Comment: @AmitK.Saha Well, yes, that's fairly obvious, but being a homework assignment doesn't make a question intrinsically bad or off-topic (though this particular one needs some work).

Comment: the threads must display the number chain like i mentioned in the question. The numbers must be the output with their respective thread name.

Answer (score 0):

Java has an interesting solution for concurrent programming/multi-threaded (MT) problems. In the "java.concurrent" asset, there is a special type of object called a lock. Because your question is somewhat vague (and possibly a homework assignment), I can only give you a basic answer. Anyways, the "lock" object provides the tools needed for threads to communicate with eachother. I would also look at delegates (a common CS solution to MT problems).

Locks: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html